# App won't launch from email link cause of missing colon

Tags: ios, email, custom-scheme-url

i have a problem to open my iOS app with a link. When I open the link it changes the url from:

```
http://myapp://my-url
```

to

```
http://myapp//my-url
```

The custom scheme does not work if there's no colon. The app is correctly setup cause when I manually type the colon back in it works like excepted.

Can someone give any advice how proceed here?

Comment: Why does the URL have two schemes (http: and myapp:)? Why isn't the URL in the email simply `myapp://my-url` ? Why is the `http://` added?

Comment: The first form is not a valid URL. What are you doing that you think you need to format it like that?

Comment: Ok I tested the same by removing the http:// on the beginning so it looks like this: myapp://my-url .Unfortunately I have still the problem that in safari it kicks out the colon..

Answer (score 0):

In Info.plist you should have such code, no : is necessary when you specify url scheme

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>myapp</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0):

you may redirect the response.
First generate the simple url when you click on that url .Redirect to your myapp://my-url(dont add http protocol now)